font-awesome load event listener
I'm trying to create a onload event listener for a Font Awsome icon
<nav class="key-icon">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-key fa-lg"></i>
</nav>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelector('nav .key-icon svg').addEventListener('load', 
    ()=> console.log('loaded')
  )
}, false)

But it's not working. Any ideas?

You don’t have an svg element

What do you hope to accomplish?

@DanielA.White the script of font-awesome creates one svg within .key-icon

@DanielA.White change dynamically the color of the icon/font

The <i> element gets replaces by a <svg> so there is no load element. You could add a mutaion observer for the parent element. But frankly you can easily change the fill color via CSS color. there is no need to wait for the svg replacement.

I found the solution, it's not particular apropriate for this svg icon but all fonts
document.fonts.ready.then(() => console.log('(SVG) Fonts loaded'))

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fonts
